# The 'kill-ie6' tag, is it worth keeping?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags

I've just noticed the `kill-ie6` [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kill-ie6) and was contemplating removing it from the questions it's been used to tag, as it seems like a tag that's not one that would be of much use for categorising questions.

Anyway - thoughts?

Comment: It's a meta tag. As it's only on 6 questions get rid of it.

Comment: @ChrisF, both valid points =) Rather than just decide "I know well enough to remove a tag from questions asked by 5 people" I thought it prudent to gather some feedback first. Having the tag remain active for a few more hours probably won't cause the world to implode ;=)

Comment: fine. But if the world does implode today, I am _so_ blaming you.

Comment: I kinda liked that tag :)

Comment: Yeah. If we still need to cater to IE6 in 2023, it will have been **your** fault!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I went ahead and merged [kill-ie6](/questions/tagged/kill-ie6) into the [internet-explorer-6](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer-6) tag.

Comment: Since when does this `[tag:stuff]` exist!?